# File missing after mv command

Tags: ubuntu, files, mv

I was trying to install ssl certs on my site. I was following a guide:

```
mkdir ssl.key
mv mydomain.key /ssl.key
```

the `mydomain.key` was in the working directory. Now it's neither in the original directory or in the folder `ssl.key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see in your `/` directory, you should see a `ssl.key` file.

`mv` is also used to change names, what your command did was:

create `ssl.key` dir in the actual path (probably `/home/user/...`

change name from `mydomain.key` to `ssl.key` and leave it in `/`

Comment: Aha thank you. So what command should I use to move them into the ssl.key directory?

Comment: it was good but if you start with `/` you are saying `absolute path` if you want a relative path just start with the dir name... something like  `mv mydomain.key ssl.key/` (Pro tip: start typing and then use the `tab` button, if the name is autocompleted, you are in the right place, if not, something is going wrong)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I  was worried I'd deleted my ssl key! I will accept this as the answer when the timer is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Were you running as root (i.e., `su` or `sudo`) when you did this? 
If so, your `mydomain.key` file is now in the root directory,
called `ssl.key`. 
Or, if you have a directory called `/ssl.key`,
then your `mydomain.key` file is now inside that.

If you weren’t running as root,
the `mv` command really should have given an error message and done nothing.

Bottom line: you should not have included the `/` in the `mv` command.